# Validacao de Erro após disparar

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

Tenho a seguinte funcao que dispara um formulario

Gostaria de caso desse erro mostrasse o showValidationError no sweetalert2.

Pelo menos para dizer que o campo é obrigatório ou erro ao salvar

```js
$('.btn-ok').on('click', function(){
forumalario()
})


async function forumalario(){

  const {value: formValues} = await Swal.fire({
    title: 'Multiple inputs',
    html:
      '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input">' +
      '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input">',
    focusConfirm: false,
    preConfirm: () => {
      return [
        document.getElementById('swal-input1').value,
        document.getElementById('swal-input2').value
      ]
    }
  })

  if (formValues) {
    console.log('campos', JSON.stringify(formValues))
    Swal.fire(json.stringify(formValues))
    
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-ok">OK</a>
```

Assim como esse exemplo de email que eles têm

```js
$('.btn-click').on('click', function(){
  click()
})

async function click(){
    const {value: email} = await Swal.fire({
    title: 'Input email address',
    input: 'email',
    inputPlaceholder: 'Enter your email address'
  })

  if (email) {
    Swal.fire('Entered email: ' + email)
  }
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
      
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-click">click</a>
```

Gostaria implementar essa validação de erro

Answer (score 0):

opa tenta assim, acho que é algo assim que você quer

```js
$('.btn-ok').on('click', function(){
forumalario()
})


async function forumalario(){

  const {value: formValues} = await Swal.fire({
    title: 'Multiple inputs',
    html:
      '<input id="swal-input1" class="swal2-input">' +
      '<input id="swal-input2" class="swal2-input">',
    focusConfirm: false,
preConfirm: () => {

        if((document.getElementById('swal-input1').value == "") || (document.getElementById('swal-input2').value == '') || ((document.getElementById('swal-input2').value == null)) ){
          Swal.showValidationMessage(
            `Esse campo não pode estar em branco`
          )
        }
      }
  })

  if (formValues) {
    console.log('campos', JSON.stringify(formValues))
    Swal.fire(json.stringify(formValues))
    
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.33.1/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-ok">OK</a>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/late-answers/367951)

Comment: Certo, ajustei o código para o Snippet